# Remote debugging path mapping

Tags: php, laravel, docker, xdebug

I want to be able to use debugger inside docker container and i managed to map entry point of laravel's `/public/index.php` to path on nginx server inside container, breakpoint in index.php is being hit, but breakpoint in default route "/" in `app/http/routes.php` is not, although route's code is being executed. It's laravel 5.1 default folder structure.

Working path mapping for index.php is `/var/www/laravel/public - C:\Users\username\Desktop\zemke2\public` (server path - project path respectively)

Printscreen here:

[image: printscreen]

I need help making mapping for "/" route's breakpoints to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some wondering I succeeded to figure it out. It is quite simple. The point is you map **FOLDERS** and you map **ABSOLUTE FILESYSTEM PATHS** on server and local. Browser url is **IRRELEVANT**, it does not matter how you run your code.

Folder containing file (or files) you want to debug on server to local folder containing that file.

In my case those are:

```
    server path: /var/www/laravel/public - local path: C:\Users\username\Desktop\zemke2\public
    server path: /var/www/laravel/app/Http - local path: C:\Users\username\Desktop\zemke2\app\Http
```

Linux paths are case sensitive. Checking `stop debugger on first line` also helps debugging problems like this.

[image: Netbeans settings.]